# Is there a way to force drush to enable a module and ignore dependencies?

Tags: 8, drush

I'm getting `exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException' with message`Configuration objects (....) provided by cn_migrator have unmet dependencies`in .../core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php:84` when trying to enable a custom migration module. I've checked the dependencies listed in the YAML files and can't see anything missing. I really need to push ahead, but can't find a way to force enabling this module.

Comment: Have you tried enabling each of the modules listed as dependencies separately; and then enabling the module in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

But, https://www.drupal.org/node/2655104 was committed today, and it allows you to see what exactly is missing. Try patching your site with that to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I've been watching that thread but unfortunately I'm running 8.1.8. I can try the patch anyway...

Comment: Th issue has been going on for a while. If the latest patch doesn't apply, try an older version.

Comment: Thanks - the patch failed on the Test files but the actual code changes applied fine to the 8.1.8 core/lib